# What is isCreatable and isUpdateable for FIELDS in GUI

Tags: apex, permissions, security, field-level-security, describesobjectresult

Where can I find and enforce "CREATABLE" and "UPDATEABLE" options for fields? Because, i am able to check the permissions in Apex(below statements) whereas, not able to **find what Creatable and updatable for fields in UI are:**

```
    if (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isUpdateable()) {
   // Update contact phone number
}


 if (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isCreateable()) {
   // Create new contact
}
```

Where do I enforce these options for fields in UI in Salesforce? or what is creatable and updateable for fields?

Comment: You can set it with FLS from Profile Or Permission set or from object manager
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_fields_fls.htm&type=5

Comment: But that includes only "Visible" Or "Read-only". My question is about "Creatable" and "Updateable".

Comment: As specified by @Phil, It has to be worked in combination  with object permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Createable means that the user can put a value in this field when they are creating a new record. Updateable means that the user can put a new value in this field when they are editing a record.

If a user has Edit permission on a field, normally Createable and Updateable will both be true. However, there are times when this won't be true.

For example, a Master-Detail relationship with "Allow reparenting" *disabled* will be Createable but not Updateable. There's some other specific system fields that have similar behavior, such as Opportunity Line Item's OpportunityId field. As far as I'm aware, there are no fields that are Updateable but not Createable.

So, you might say that these two permissions are a combination of the user's Field Level Security and the field's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Updatable for a field means the user has update permission for the object containing the field and has edit permission for the field.

Creatable for a field means the user has create permission for the object containing the field and has edit permission for the field.